# Calculate day time differences in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
 data = [
("10/10/2016","A"),
("10/10/2016","B"),
("09/12/2016","B"),
("09/12/2016","A"),
("08/11/2016","A"),
("08/11/2016","C")] 

#Create DataFrame base
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=("Time","User"))

# Convert time column to correct format for time calculations
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Each row represents when a user makes a specific action. I want to compute how frequently (in terms of days) **each** user makes that specific action.

Let's say user A transacted first time on 08/11/2016, and then he transacted again on 09/12/2016, i.e. around 30 days after. Then, he transacted again on 10/10/2016, around 29 days after his second transaction. So, his average frequency in days would be (29+30)/2.

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

---

- Update

---

I wrote the following function that computes my desired output.

```
from datetime import timedelta

def averagetime(a):
    numdeltas = len(a) - 1
    sumdeltas = 0

    i = 1
    while i < len(a):
        delta = abs((a[i] - a[i-1]).days)
        sumdeltas += delta
        i += 1

    if numdeltas > 1:
        avg = sumdeltas / numdeltas
    else:
        avg = 'NaN'  
    return avg
```

It works correctly, for example, when I pass the whole "Time" column:

```
averagetime(df["Time"])
```

But it gives me an error when I try to apply it after group by.

```
df.groupby('User')['Time'].apply(averagetime)
```

Any suggestions how I can fix the above?

Comment: Not the exact answer, but perhaps you would try googling [pairwise difference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiohv3d5KvNAhVU0WMKHYHWCR0QFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F21467429%2Fpairwise-matrix-from-a-pandas-dataframe&usg=AFQjCNG1vrKJgkLxfWwiCwHyDRTzG1aevA&sig2=1qi6JGBnoqNr7UFuT_3xPw)

Comment: Can you add desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html), convert to `float` by [`np.timedelta64(1,'D')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion) and with [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) count [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
print (averagetime(df["Time"]))
12.0

su = ((df["Time"].diff() / np.timedelta64(1,'D')).abs().sum())
print (su / (len(df) - 1))
12.0
```

Then I apply it to `groupby`, but there is necessary condition, because:

> ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

```
print (df.groupby('User')['Time']
         .apply(lambda x: np.nan if len(x) == 1 
                                 else (x.diff()/np.timedelta64(1,'D')).abs().sum()/(len(x)-1)))

User
A    30.0
B    28.0
C     NaN
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Great solution! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Building on from @Jezrael's answer:

If by "how frequently" you mean - how much time passes between each user performing the action then here's an approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ("10/10/2016","A"),
    ("10/10/2016","B"),
    ("09/12/2016","B"),
    ("09/12/2016","A"),
    ("08/11/2016","A"),
    ("08/11/2016","C"),
]

# Create DataFrame base
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=("Time","User"))

# Convert time column to correct format for time calculations
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], dayfirst=True)

# Group the DF by min, max and count the number of instances
grouped = (df.groupby("User").agg([np.max, np.min, np.count_nonzero])

           # This step is a bit messy and could be improved,
           # but we need the count as an int
           .assign(counter=lambda x: x["Time"]["count_nonzero"].astype(int))

           # Use apply to calculate the time between first and last, then divide by frequency
           .apply(lambda x: (x["Time"]["amax"] - x["Time"]["amin"]) / x["counter"].astype(int), axis=1)
           )

# Output the DF if using an interactive prompt
grouped
```

Output:

```
User    
A   20 days
B   30 days
C   0 days
```